# Need help identifying this track from Sucker Punch movie

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Does anyone know the name of the song heard during the fight with the first Samurai? It's not on the officially released *Sucker Punch* soundtrack.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD6HagsWk8A

Comment: A new link was found, not sure if it'll throw off the timecodes in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am unsure about the first minutes of the music, but it seems consistent with this:

Army of Me [Sucker Punch Remix] - Björk (feat. Skunk Anansie)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLab8PWsZKg

Sources:

- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucker_Punch_(soundtrack)
- IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0978764/soundtrack

<sub>Yes, I tried them all, one by one</sub>

---

**Edit:**

As referred to in a comment, the time interval is from 1:02 to 2:11.

The same guitar can be listened from minute 3:46 and on.

Link with the timestamp: https://youtu.be/bLab8PWsZKg?t=226

Comment: Army Of Me is what's used for the death of the 2nd Samurai and the fight with the 3rd.  I'm looking just for what's used for the fight with the 1st Samurai.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Can you provide the offsets in time, so I can compare it more accurately?

Comment: 1:02 to 2:11 in that clip.  Heavily guitar-riff oriented.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Give me 30 minutes, and I will get back to you with more info. And possibly an edit/deletition.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Excuse the 7 minute long delay. I've edited the question. You can listen to the same guitar from 3:46 on the youtube link I've provided. If you want to skip directly to the time: https://youtu.be/Zce1QaicJTs?t=3m46s

Comment: Sounds like it's a remix of a remix.  :o)  Definitely the same riff.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Probably someone will remix that. And thanks for accepting this answer. I'm really sorry that someone downvoted your question. It really was hard to find the exact song. And if I didn't had your help, I would never find the right time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, it's Frank Zappa with "I'm so cute" I think, at least the riffs reminded me of it. Here is the link to it